# Convert geopandas.geodataframe to geojson

Tags: python, geojson, osmnx, fiona

I am trying to save a geopandas.geodataframe in geojson format. but i have an error and i don't know where it comes from and how to solve it. here is the code and the error :

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
  batiments = ox.geometries_from_place(saint_denis, tags={'building':['office', 
  'university', 'stadium', 
                                                      'civic']})
  routes = ox.geometries_from_place(saint_denis, tags={'highway':['primary', 
 'secondary']})
  #export to geojson 
  batiments.to_file('dataframe.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.to_file()`
You can either create a new geojson file and fill the `.to_json()` object inside it , it's a json dict in (str) format.

```
with open('dataframe.geojson' , 'w') as file:
    file.write(batiments.to_json())
```